# can't figure out the logic to make the values add up

Tags: javascript

I'm making a calculator project but as for now, my calculator can only perform the action of summing two numbers instead of adding up all the numbers that we add up later. I can't figure out the logic to make this work for it to calculate the numbers in a sequencial manner. Can anyone help me with this?

For example, now when you press 2 + 2 it returns 4, but when you press 2 + 2 + 4 it returns 6 and it should behave like a normal calculator, returning 8

I would relaly appreciate it thank you! Here is the script for my program:

```
var select = document.querySelector('#buttons')
var operating = document.querySelector('#operators')
let buttonequals = document.getElementById('button-equals')

select.addEventListener('click', selector)
operating.addEventListener('click', operatorSign)


let value;
let target;
let firstResult = 0;
let secondResult = 0;
let finalResult = 0;
let operand = "";


function selector(event) {
  target = event.target;
  if (target.matches('button')) {
    value = target.innerHTML
    value = Number(value);

    result = document.querySelector('#output').value += value
    result = Number(result)


    if (operand === "") {
      firstResult = Number(result)
      console.log(firstResult)
    } else {
      secondResult = Number(result)
      console.log(secondResult)
    }


  }}


function operatorSign(e) {
    let operator = e.target;
    if (operator.matches('button')) {
      operand = operator.innerHTML

      if (operand !== "=") {
          document.querySelector('#output').value = ""

      }

    }
}


function calculate() {


  if (operand === "+") {
    finalResult = firstResult + secondResult
    document.querySelector('#output').value = finalResult
    console.log(finalResult)
  } else if (operand === "-") {
    finalResult = firstResult - secondResult
    document.querySelector('#output').value = finalResult
  } else if (operand === "*") {
    finalResult = firstResult * secondResult
    document.querySelector('#output').value = finalResult
  } else if (operand === "/") {
    finalResult = firstResult / secondResult
    document.querySelector('#output').value = finalResult
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide example(s) of how this should behave?

Comment: now when you press 2 + 2 it returns 4, but when you press 2 + 2 + 4 it returns 6 and it should behave like a normal calculator, returning 8

Comment: And what part of this code is attempting to provide this running total?

Comment: calculate() function

Comment: And what is `calculate` doing to attempt to accomplish this?

Comment: when the equal button is clicked, it sums the firstResult and secondResult

Comment: How. Does. That. Contribute. To. Running. Total. ?

Comment: that's the problem. I don't know how to make the running total

Comment: yeah, but it is not here

Comment: i wanted to make the code as clean as possible

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Spread Operator` to get a variable number of argument and then calculate the sum.
Something like below:

```
function calculate(...arg) {
    const sum = arg.reduce((acc, v) => {
  acc = acc + v;
  return acc;
  })
  console.log(sum);
}

calculate(1,2);
calculate(1,2,3,4);
```